# Column-conditional merging of dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes `df1`

```
        index         x0             y0              x1               y1
0       0            4406             670            4558             760
1       1            3762             655            3913             747
2       2            3080             646            3235             741
3       3             311             616             465             709
4       4             402            1359             543            1449
5       5             594             618             750             710
6       6            3267            2345            3389            2425
7       7            2297             632            2459             731
8       8            2065            1066            2219            1159
9       9             338             999             486            1094
10     10            1748             627            1908             722
11     11            2761            1471            2898            1555
12     12             831            1004             982            1099
13     13            3899            2353            4014            2425
14     14            2761            2822            2880            2894
15     15            3350            1953            3476            2032
16     16             863            1367             996            1452
17     17            2698            1951            2824            2038
18     18               1             610             160             708
19     19            1322            1054            1468            1151
20     20            1447            2261            1571            2344
21     21               0            1354             111            1449
22     22            1391            1506            1530            1592
23     23            1498            2817            1616            2893
24     24            3632            2808            3748            2880
25     25            1090             624            1246             715
26     26            4500            1488            4608            1562
27     27            1440             626            1593             717
28     28            2671            2345            2790            2421
29     29            3827            1951            3949            2030
30     30            3366            1079            3510            1171
31     31            1406            1903            1541            1993
32     32            3722            1477            3859            1565
33     33            4122            1486            4252            1562
34     34             915            1777            1047            1863
35     35            4201            1094            4338            1181
36     36            4399            1964            4514            2029
37     37            4529            1098            4608            1181
38     38             477            1775             609            1861
39     39            4435            2349            4543            2414
40     40              67            1773             201            1858
```

and `df2`

```
     item     x     y
0   110786  3211   677
1   107099  3492  1109
2   168977   140   644
3   110973  4324  1120
4   105162  3373  2376
5   107101   720   648
6   169062  1444  1087
7   104530  2808  1984
8   103803  3460  1980
9   168977   130   637
10  107100  2876  1501
11  107098   587  1804
12  109364  1886   659
13  168144   522  1386
14  165044  1573   655
15  165045  1224   652
16  156596  4536   698
17  169063  2196  1094
18  107181  1508  1534
19  107879  1516  1933
20  105163  2858  2844
21  110773  3892   684
22  110775  2430   662
23  167458   958  1033
24  105161  3730  2830
25  105160  2772  2372
26  107292  1548  2290
27  109058  4000  2376
28  105317  4604  1512
29  168146    83  1386
30  109057  4529  2369
31  105316  4237  1508
32  110782  1595  2840
33  110774   457  1030
34  107211  3935  1973
```

As you can see, `df1` has 41 rows, while `df1` has 35 AND more importantly, they have no common index or value to merge them on. However, there is a relation which I want to use to merge them.

Basically, what I want to do is to merge in the following way:

If for a given row of `df2` we have `x0<x<x1` and `y0<y<y1`, then the row of `df2` containing `(x,y)` satisfying that condition is appended to the right row of `df1`.

Of course, since `df1` has more rows than `df2`, the resulting dataframe (with 45 rows) will contain `nan` for those rows that could not be matched.
Also, there is no chance of `(x,y)` being matched to more than one row of `df1` since the "boxes"  described by `x0,x1,y0,y1` are disjoint.

I tried to use `np.where()` statements but failed miserably.

Any idea on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like just cross merge and query:

```
(df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key')
    .query('x0<x<x1 and y0<y<y1')
)
```

Output, notice `index=18` is duplicated, what do you want to do with these two lines?

```
      index    x0    y0    x1    y1  key    item     x     y
16        0  4406   670  4558   760    1  156596  4536   698
56        1  3762   655  3913   747    1  110773  3892   684
70        2  3080   646  3235   741    1  110786  3211   677
153       4   402  1359   543  1449    1  168144   522  1386
180       5   594   618   750   710    1  107101   720   648
214       6  3267  2345  3389  2425    1  105162  3373  2376
267       7  2297   632  2459   731    1  110775  2430   662
297       8  2065  1066  2219  1159    1  169063  2196  1094
348       9   338   999   486  1094    1  110774   457  1030
362      10  1748   627  1908   722    1  109364  1886   659
395      11  2761  1471  2898  1555    1  107100  2876  1501
443      12   831  1004   982  1099    1  167458   958  1033
482      13  3899  2353  4014  2425    1  109058  4000  2376
510      14  2761  2822  2880  2894    1  105163  2858  2844
533      15  3350  1953  3476  2032    1  103803  3460  1980
602      17  2698  1951  2824  2038    1  104530  2808  1984
632      18     1   610   160   708    1  168977   140   644
639      18     1   610   160   708    1  168977   130   637
671      19  1322  1054  1468  1151    1  169062  1444  1087
726      20  1447  2261  1571  2344    1  107292  1548  2290
764      21     0  1354   111  1449    1  168146    83  1386
788      22  1391  1506  1530  1592    1  107181  1508  1534
837      23  1498  2817  1616  2893    1  110782  1595  2840
864      24  3632  2808  3748  2880    1  105161  3730  2830
890      25  1090   624  1246   715    1  165045  1224   652
938      26  4500  1488  4608  1562    1  105317  4604  1512
959      27  1440   626  1593   717    1  165044  1573   655
1005     28  2671  2345  2790  2421    1  105160  2772  2372
1049     29  3827  1951  3949  2030    1  107211  3935  1973
1051     30  3366  1079  3510  1171    1  107099  3492  1109
1104     31  1406  1903  1541  1993    1  107879  1516  1933
1186     33  4122  1486  4252  1562    1  105316  4237  1508
1228     35  4201  1094  4338  1181    1  110973  4324  1120
1341     38   477  1775   609  1861    1  107098   587  1804
1395     39  4435  2349  4543  2414    1  109057  4529  2369
```

Comment: Take alook at `merge` with parameter `how='cross'` instead of assigning key. `df1.merge(df2, how='cross').query(.....)`

Comment: Just add to @ScottBoston's comment, `how='cross'` is available on Pandas 1.2.0+ (I think).